# Graviton-fermion vertices

Tags: feynman-diagrams, fermions

I'm trying to derive the Feynman rules for a graviton-fermion interaction. I know the interaction term in Lagrangian densities

$\mathscr{L}_ {int}=-\frac{\kappa}{2}h^{\mu \nu}[\frac{i}{2}\bar{\psi} \gamma_{\mu}\overleftrightarrow{\partial_{\nu}}\psi -\eta_{\mu \nu}\bar{\psi}(\frac{i}{2}\gamma^{\rho}\overleftrightarrow{\partial_{\rho}} - m_{\psi})\psi$

Could anyone help me with this issue? Unfortunately, I don't have much experience with working with fermions. I know what should I do with the graviton and the derivatives acting on $\psi$, but I have problem with single fermion fields e.g. in terms $h^{\mu \nu}\bar{\psi} \gamma_{\mu}\overleftrightarrow{\partial_{\nu}}\psi$.

Comment: You might want to check "Quantum Mechanics of the Interaction of Gravity with Electrons Theory of a Spin Two Field Coupled to Energy" by Huggins.